# Get previous X days of available data, skipping days without data

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table that has daily data and thousands of rows per day:

```sql
create table my_table(visitors_count int, dt date);

select setseed(.42);

insert into my_table 
select (random()*100)::int, 
       current_date+(-random()*14)::int
from generate_series(1,42000);
```

However, some days are not present due to holidays:

```sql
delete from my_table where dt = '2024-03-08';
```

I need a query that would check if the initial date has data, and if it does, retrieves the data for the previous 5 days.

Example: If I put in today's date `2024/3/12`, I would need to

1. Check if `2024/3/12` has data.
2. If yes, retrieve data for March `7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11` and `12`:

   |  |
   | --- |
   | 2024-03-**07** |
   | 2024-03-**08** |
   | 2024-03-**09** |
   | 2024-03-10 |
   | 2024-03-11 |
   | 2024-03-12 |
3. However, if let's say the 8th is a holiday and there was no data, I would need data for `6`,`7`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`:

   |  |
   | --- |
   | 2024-03-**06** |
   | 2024-03-**07** |
   | 2024-03-**09** |
   | 2024-03-10 |
   | 2024-03-11 |
   | 2024-03-12 |

Comment: Please attach your current query, even if it's just a non-functional sketch, along with `create table` and `insert` statements showing the schema and some mock/sample rows, plus what you expect to get on output. It sounds like joining with `generate_series()` and filtering on `date_part('dow', dt)` or window functions could do what you want.

Comment: You say *check if the initial date has data, and if it does ...*. Well what do you do if that initial date does not have data?

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE, you can get the last 5 dates preceding your date of interest using [`limit 6`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html#QUERIES-LIMIT) and ordering by the date. And only returning results when the date of interest exists in the table. Then select all data points from your table that match those 6 dates (if any): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9AHQgfcI)

```sql
with last5dates as (
    select distinct mydate
    from my_table mdt
    where mdt.mydate <= '2024-03-12'
    order by mdt.mydate desc
    limit 6 )    
select distinct mydate
from my_table 
inner join last5dates using (mydate)
order by mydate;
```

| mydate |
| --- |
| 2024-03-06 |
| 2024-03-07 |
| 2024-03-09 |
| 2024-03-10 |
| 2024-03-11 |
| 2024-03-12 |

Answer (score 0):

Set up [a window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) to order by date descending and use [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to assign the same numbers to the same dates - it will skip the empty ones. Then ask for only those up to 5 days back: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/uGlMV2wF)

```sql
with data_by_days_back as (
  select *,dense_rank()over w1 as days_back 
  from my_table 
  where dt<='2024-03-12' --start date
  window w1 as (order by dt desc) )
select distinct dt, days_back --checking which dates got caught
from data_by_days_back
where days_back<=6 --number of non-empty days back from the start 
order by dt;
```

| dt | days_back |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-03-06 | 6 |
| 2024-03-07 | 5 |
| 2024-03-09 | 4 |
| 2024-03-10 | 3 |
| 2024-03-11 | 2 |
| 2024-03-12 | 1 |